# Adding programmatically label with relative constraint issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I've an `UITableView` with some cells, in the first cell I would like to add multiple `UILabel`. That's the code I am using inside a function in `UITableViewCell` sub class (called in `cellForRowAt`):

```
    ...
let constantTop = 16


    for (index,optional) in optionals.enumerated(){
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "\(optional.name)"
        label.tag = 10010132
        label.font = CocoFonts.semibold(size: 15)
        label.textColor = CocoColors.FedericoMalagoni.textVeryDarkBlue

        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        let constant:CGFloat = CGFloat(constantTop * (index + 1))

        print(constant)

        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)

        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)

        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)


        let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.lblInfo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: constant)

        let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: constant)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, top, bottom, height])

    }
    self.contentView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
...
```

Now, 
The labels are over the edge of the cell like this:

[image]

The gray separator divide the cell.
Essentially the height of the cell is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if you could share full implementation of cellForRowAt. 
I faced similar issue where cell contents were overlapping. I was adding custom view to the cell as subview.

This happens because Table view re uses its cells. So one solution is to remove old label from the cell before you add new.

```
for content in cell.contentView.subviews {
   content.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: I’ll provide a new screenshot so you can understans better

Comment: Yes it will be very helpful if you provide full implementation detail for cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  I assumed your issue is similar to that of mine.